# TableLayoutPanel swaps controls position when other some other TableLayoutPanel control is not visible

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

In my designer I made a tableLayoutPanel where each cell has a Checkbox. As I show below

[image: designer tableLayoutPanel]

I want to only make the checkboxes  from 0 to 14 visible.
But at runtime it swaps 12 and 14 and I really don't know why (see 2nd image).

[image: runtime tableLayoutPanel]

I tried to delete tableLayoutPanel and rebuild a new one but it swaps the checkboxes again...

Note: If I make all checkboxes visible then the swap does not happen

If I swap checkbox 14 and 12 in designer it will show correctly on runtime, but I want to know why this swap happens

Comment: how do you make them invisible? in the designer? or code?

Comment: Go into designer after issue occurs (stop application) and right click buttons and select properties.  Your code someplace must be doing the swapping if the properties are correct.  Either then name of the property got swapped or just the value.  The designer when stopped should have last values when code ran.

Comment: @MongZhu I made invisible with designer properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found out the reason, by some reason in the designer when I added the checkboxes in each column, the code generated in Form.Designer.cs added all checkboxes to the first column.

```cs
this.tlpRob1Cartao.Controls.Add(this.ckRob1Cartao12, 0, 2);
this.tlpRob1Cartao.Controls.Add(this.ckRob1Cartao13, 0, 2);
this.tlpRob1Cartao.Controls.Add(this.ckRob1Cartao14, 0, 2);
this.tlpRob1Cartao.Controls.Add(this.ckRob1Cartao15, 0, 2);
this.tlpRob1Cartao.Controls.Add(this.ckRob1Cartao16, 0, 2);
this.tlpRob1Cartao.Controls.Add(this.ckRob1Cartao17, 0, 2);
```

Note: The 2nd argument is the column index (the zeros argument)

All I needed to do was write (in Form.Designer.cs)  the correct column index as below:

```cs
this.tlpRob1Cartao.Controls.Add(this.ckRob1Cartao12, 0, 2);
this.tlpRob1Cartao.Controls.Add(this.ckRob1Cartao13, 1, 2);
this.tlpRob1Cartao.Controls.Add(this.ckRob1Cartao14, 2, 2);
this.tlpRob1Cartao.Controls.Add(this.ckRob1Cartao15, 3, 2);
this.tlpRob1Cartao.Controls.Add(this.ckRob1Cartao16, 4, 2);
this.tlpRob1Cartao.Controls.Add(this.ckRob1Cartao17, 5, 2);
```

Comment: @MongZhu Sorry, I am new to ask questions and write answers. Is there any other mistake that you see?

Comment: looks fine to me now